# TypeError: ref.key is not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**AngularJS:** v1.5.11
**Firebase:** v3.6.9 
**Angularfire:** v2.3.0

I want to get the key. After creating the JSON object my code :

```
  }).then(function(ref){
          var id = ref.key();
          console.log("Added User with ID: "+id);
```

The value is inserted in the firebase DB but getting this error and nothing is shown in the console log.

I guess the syntax to get the key is changed with these versions. I don't know what the `ref.key()` is used for really. Is it required as to set some primary key?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reference.key()` used to be a function in Firebase JavaScript SDK 2.x. But is is now a read-only property, so you should use `ref.key`.

This and many more things to be aware of when upgrading your code are covered in the Firebase migration guide for web developers: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Comment: Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

```js
}).then(function(ref){
          var id = ref.key();// remove this
          var id = ref.key;  // use this 
          console.log("Added User with ID: "+id);
```

var id=ref.key()

In this line of code you need to use "ref.key" instead of "ref.key()"